# Unable to install pandas library

Tags: pandas, metadata, python-wheel, meson-build, pyproject.toml

I get this error message whenever I try installing pandas library:

C:\Windows\system32>pip install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas
Using cached pandas-2.1.1.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
+ meson setup C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7.mesonpy-2lj4p08p\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7.mesonpy-2lj4p08p\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.1
Source dir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7
Build dir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7.mesonpy-2lj4p08p\build
Build type: native build
Project name: pandas
Project version: 2.1.1

```
  ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ep3pfy9e\pandas_204be4fbdfdb4eef8e68ac98d10382d7\.mesonpy-2lj4p08p\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried upgrading pip but still didn't work
I tried installing Visual Studio installer packages but still it hasn't worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to install pandas library but whenever i try doing it using the command prompt, I get the error message

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue today and I may have a temporary solution for you.

```
pip install pandas==2.0.3
```

Version 2.1.1 failed to install for me and I couldn't find a satisfactory answer after a little research. But installing an earlier version from the ones listed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/index.html#version-2-0) seems to be a workaround. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a 32-bit version of python and pandas does not work on 32-bit since version 2.1 as they now require PyArrow as prerequisite and PyArrow doesn’t support 32-bit which you can confirm via `pip install pyarrow`. So @A.Raamiz solution is the best.